# How can i compile ps command from a source code?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc

I got a file ps.c from the site: git.suckless.org/ubase and i want to compile it with command gcc ps.c but im getting errors like this:

[image]

is it even possible to compile this, or is there any other way to compile ps command from source code?